# Can't mount Raspberry Pi NFS Server

Tags: mount, nfs

I am trying to set up my pi3 running raspbian as an NFS server. I've followed these instructions: http://www.htpcguides.com/configure-nfs-server-and-nfs-client-raspberry-pi/

In /etc/exports I have the line:

```
/mnt/Shared 192.168.1.0/24 *(rw,sync)
```

Which I hope means that the folder at /mnt/Shared (which is a directory on an external hard drive) is available for reading and writing by all machines using a local IP address. Then I do exportfs:

```
$ sudo exportfs
/mnt/Shared    192.168.1.0/24
/mnt/Shared    <world>
```

Then, on my laptop, which is running Ubuntu, I follow the client side instructions from the same site, but the mount command fails after a long wait:

```
$ sudo mount 192.168.1.105:/mnt/Shared /mnt/nfs
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

If I try that verbose it looks like this:

```
sudo mount -v 192.168.1.105:/mnt/Shared /mnt/nfs/
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sat Feb 18 21:52:14 2017
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.105,clientaddr=192.168.1.109'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Connection refused
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.105,clientaddr=192.168.1.109'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Connection refused
...
<repeated several times>
...
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

Has anyone any ideas of how to make it work? I don't think the problem is with the external hard drive, it appears to be mounted correctly, and I had the same issues trying to share a local directory.

Comment: I've got it to work! A commenter on this question (http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/48091/nfs-file-sharing-not-working-with-raspberry-pi-3?rq=1) suggested trying "sudo systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server" after each reboot of the system, and since I've done that it seems to work. I need to figure out how to make that happen automatically after each reboot. Once I've done that I'll add it as an answer, unless someone has a better solution in the mean time.

Comment: I'm not sure the result of the exportfs is remembered across boots.  Try putting the exportfs data in /etc/exports or under /etc/exports.d.  There should be no need to restart nfs-kernel-server if the nfs configuration files are correct.

Answer (score 0):

First I would make the following bash script and call it delay:

```
#!/bin/bash
# $1：delay time(s)
# $2：command
# example:
#    delay 10 "conky -d"

sleep $1
exec $2
```

Then I would make it executable

```
chmod a+x delay
```

You could put the command from your comments:

```
delay 60 "sudo systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server"
```

at the end of the rc.local file `in /etc/init.d/` to have it run 60 seconds after every time the Pi boots up

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I'm afraid it doesn't seem to be working. After a reboot the drives still wont mount until I run the command myself through ssh.

Comment: @eddytheb I've made an edit to my answer can you please try it now?

Comment: Thanks again, but I'm afraid it still doesn't seem to be working. Your delay script works, but when I reboot the pi I still have to ssh in and run the restart command myself before the folder becomes visible (even after waiting much longer than a minute).

Answer (score 0):

**On the RPi NFS Server** (The Media Server)

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rpcbind restart
sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart
```

**On the RPi NFS Client** (My Plex Server)

```
sudo mount 192.168.1.105:/mnt/Shared /mnt/nfs
```

This worked for me.

And I had to mount my drives including the uid/gid in `/etc/fstap` because in my case `chown` does not work when the drive is mounted by root.
Maybe someone can give me a tip for that.

Answer (score 0):

Tell reboot to wait for the network to be available. It’s on raspi-config in the advanced section iirc